# How to clear the value of all input filed?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear the value of all input filed having class class="axs" inside a given DIV with a button. I am using this JavaScript code:

Using pure vanilla JavaScript how to remove the value attribute like `value= ''`

```js
let content = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
let el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = content;
let textS = el.querySelectorAll(".axs");
for (let i = 0; i < textS.length; i++) {
  let id = textS[i].id;
  el.getElementById(id).value = '';
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div>
    <input class="axs" id="1" type="text" value="1650" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="2" type="text" value="850" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="3" type="text" value="340" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="4" type="text" value="321" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="5" type="text" value="567" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="6" type="text" value="890" spellcheck="false">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've selected `.anx` but all the inputs have the `.axs` class name?

Comment: Why do you have the variable `el` at all?

Comment: i have to further use it so that is why i am using this

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".axs").forEach(x => x.value = '');
```

First the method `querySelectorAll` matches all elements with class name `.axs` and puts them into an array. Then I use the forEach method to loop every element, which I call x and then I set the value of x to empty for each one.

Comment: It would be useful to explain how your answer works, especially for those not familiar with `...` and `forEach`

Comment: Array casting is not necessary here. NodeList is iterable, so you can use forEach method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here an adjusted version of your script

```js
let textS = document.querySelectorAll(".axs");
for (let i = 0; i < textS.length; i++) {
  textS[i].value = '';
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div>
    <input class="axs" id="1" type="text" value="1650" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="2" type="text" value="850" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="3" type="text" value="340" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="4" type="text" value="321" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="5" type="text" value="567" spellcheck="false">
    <input class="axs" id="6" type="text" value="890" spellcheck="false">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i cannot use document here is there a way i can do the operation on ```el```

Comment: Why can't you use the `document`? If you truly can't, that information - among with an explanation (to preempt questions such as my own) - should be included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are confusing the value of the attribute linked to an input and the current value of an input.

formally you must use a reset and a form replace all the values of the inputs by those fixed in their attribute

> example 1:

```js
const 
  myForm     = document.forms['my-form']
, All_Inputs = myForm.querySelectorAll('input')

myForm.clearBt.onclick = () =>
  {
  All_Inputs.forEach(el=> el.value='')
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">

  <input name="axs1"  type="text" value="1650" placeholder="axs1">
  <input name="axs2"  type="text" value="232" placeholder="axs2">
  <input name="axs3"  type="text" value="789" placeholder="axs3">

  <button type="reset"> real form reset</button>
  <button type="button" name="clearBt"> just clear inputs</button>
  
</form>

<p> the clear button doesn't change the input attribute, <br>
 and the default values goes back whith the reset button.
</p>
```

> example 2:

```js
const 
  myForm     = document.forms['my-form']
, All_Inputs = myForm.querySelectorAll('input')

myForm.clearBt.onclick = () =>
  {
  All_Inputs.forEach(el=>el.setAttribute('value',''))
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">

  <input name="axs1"  type="text" value="1650" placeholder="axs1">
  <input name="axs2"  type="text" value="4898" placeholder="axs2">
  <input name="axs3"  type="text" value="12" placeholder="axs3">

  <button type="reset"> real form reset</button>
  <button type="button" name="clearBt">  clear inputs attributes</button>
  
</form>

<p> the clear button change the input attribute, <br>
 and the default values will be definitely changed for the reset button.
</p>
```

> so, for your question :
>
> ```js
> document
>   .querySelectorAll('input.axs')
>   .forEach(el=> el.setAttribute('value',''))
>
> console.log( document.querySelector('div').innerHTML )
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div id="output">
>   <div>
>     <input class="axs" id="1" type="text" value="1650" spellcheck="false">
>     <input class="axs" id="2" type="text" value="850" spellcheck="false">
>     <input class="axs" id="3" type="text" value="340" spellcheck="false">
>     <input class="axs" id="4" type="text" value="321" spellcheck="false">
>     <input class="axs" id="5" type="text" value="567" spellcheck="false">
>     <input class="axs" id="6" type="text" value="890" spellcheck="false">
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this JS snippet:

```
let textS = document.querySelectorAll(".axs");
textS.forEach(inp => inp.value = '');
```